# Upgrade SQL Server to a specific build?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to install the Sharepoint 2010 beta, but have been running into a problem with my SQL Server.  Sharepoint says it is expecting version 10.00.2714.00, and my SQL Server is version 10.0.1600.22.  I have applied every CU up to CU7 but my SQL Server version number has not changed.  I am using the full enterprise edition of SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Very strange indeed.  Just for your info, 10.00.2714.00 corresponds to SP1 CU2.

Comment: Have you been able to verify that the updates actually occurred, whether through event log entries or modification dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter how many CUs you apply to RTM, if the Share Points needs SP1, then it will continue to complain. You need to install SP1 (which will bring the version to 10.00.2531) and then isntall the SP1 CUs to roll forward the version to 10.00.2714.

The first number in the build number is the SP level (1xxx is RTM, 2xxx is SP1, 3xxx will be SP2 etc).